# Swift: How to find the indices of the maximum values along an axis in a multi dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to find the indices of the maximum values along axis 0 in a multi dimensional array. This can be done in `python` using `numpy`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

In `python`:

```
a = array([[1,2,3],[4,3,1]])
a.argmax(axis=0)
```

Will return:

```
array([1, 1, 0])
```

How would one do the exact same thing in `swift`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple implementation, not actually very safe because it is based on the precondition that all subarrays have the same length and are not empty:

```
extension Array where Element == [Int] {
    func axisItems(axis: Int) -> [[Int]] {
        // let's suppose all elements have the same length
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }

        switch axis {
        case 0:
            // transpose
            return self[0].indices.map { index in self.map { $0[index] } }
        case 1:
            return self
        default:
            fatalError("Invalid axis: \(axis)")
        }
    }

    func argMax(axis: Int) -> [Int] {
         // add indices to items, find max item and return its index
        return axisItems(axis: axis).map { $0.enumerated().max { $0.1 < $1.1 }!.0 }
    }
}

let array: [[Int]] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1]]
print(array.argMax(axis: 0)) // [1, 1, 0]
print(array.argMax(axis: 1)) // [2, 0]
```

I am transposing the matrix for `axis = 0`.

This is not easily extensible for arrays with higher dimensions. For that it would be better to use a custom object instead of an array.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot. How would one make a 3 dimensional input possible as well?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen I am not sure what is the expected result in a 3D array because one axis in a 3D array is a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the fellowing code:

```
let a = Array([[1,2,4],[4,3,1]])
func findMax(on axis: Int, in array: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    let result: [Int]
    if axis == 0 {
        result = array.map() {
            $0.index(of: $0.max()!)! // Make sure the array is not empty
        }
    } else {
        result = findMax(on: 0, in: transpose(array: array))
    }
    return result
}
func transpose(array: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    let d1 = array.count
    let d2 = array[0].count // Take the length of the first sub array(first row).  

    var result: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: Array.init(repeating: 0, count: d1), count: d2)
    for (k, a) in array.enumerated() {
        for (i, v) in a.enumerated() {
            result[i][k] = v
        }
    }
    return result
}

findMax(on: 0, in: a) // [2, 0] 
findMax(on: 1, in: a) // [1, 1, 0]
```

It's not a rigorous demo.
But I think this can inspire you.